# How to properly clean up dangling data in a persisted in memory store?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have written a [small framework](https://state-less.cloud) which allows me to use TSX components on the server side and write my backend code using a reactive approach known from react. (components, hooks).

The states being used by components on the server side are being kept in memory for now (but the problem stays the same once they are externalized to a database).

Suppose I create various states on the server side due to client server interaction (e.g. through a webapp).

For example if you head over to our example Lists app (https://state-less.cloud/lists?fs) and create a few lists with todo items, this will create an in memory representation of your backends components states on the server side.

The serverside code which renders the list looks as follows

```
// ...
<ServerSideProps
    key={clientKey('my-lists-props', context)}
    add={addEntry}
    remove={removeEntry}
    order={order}
    setOrder={setOrder}
    exportUserData={exportUserData}
    importUserData={importUserData}
>
    {lists.map((list) => (
        <List key={`list-${list.id}`} {...list} />
    ))}
</ServerSideProps>
```

Now suppose you delete a list. At the moment the object is simply removed from the array (lists). This means the serverside component that managed the state of the list you just deleted won't be rendered anymore. This means all the states it used are still in memory but will never be needed again.

I have two options to delete an item from the `lists` array. From within the `List` component or from within the parent component. If I call a `delete` methode on the `List` component, I could invoke a `destroy` function that deletes any state used by the component from memory.

But this imposes the restriction that I can only modify the `lists` array / state from within a child component even though it is instantiated in the parent component. So not being able to modify the state from the parent component feels wrong.

I think it should be allowed to simply not render a component but then I don't know how to know when I can clean up its data in memory.

Maybe I need to implement some sort of garbage collection algorithm. e.g.

1. unmount all components upon a rerender
2. mount all newly rendered components
3. delete all unmounted components from memory

Now this could delete states of components which will possibly be rendered again later. (e.g. hiding / showing items).

Maybe add a TTL so data get's deleted after 30days of inactivity.

Maybe the only clean option is to impose the restriction to invoke an operation that removes items from a list from the child component only (to be able to properly clean up any state).

How is this handled by react on the frontend? What happens if you omit a previously rendered component and render it again? Do their states get recreated, do they get deleted from memory if they are not being rendered in the next render cycle?

Maybe I could use the same approach.

TLDR; How can I properly clean up any dangling states when dynamically rendering child components?